# Why does b >>> 1 always equals -1 when b is a byte and has value -1 in Java?

Tags: java, binary, byte, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I know that `>>>` is unsigned shift-right, and since `byte` in Java is signed 8-bit then -1 will be represented as `1111 1111`. As a result, for the code below:

```java
byte b = (byte) -1;
b >>>= 1;
System.out.println(b);
```

Shouldn't it print `127` (0111 1111 in binary)? But the result I get is always `-1`, no matter how many times I perform `>>>` to `b` (e.g. in a loop).

Can anyone explain why and in what way I can get the result I expect (i.e. to perform unsigned right shift in which `-1` shifted right once equals `127` for a `byte` in Java)? Is my understanding wrong? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're running into a chain of really weird java design choices that make this code 'lie' (it *appears* to do one thing but it actually won't do that thing). Let's break it down:

#### Lesser known java aspect 1: `byte`, `short`, `char`, and `boolean` are inferior

In java, `byte`, `short`, `char`, `boolean` are the **inferior** primitives, with `int`, `long`, `double` and `float` being the **superior** primitives. There are no opcodes for the inferiors beyond array store and array load. **There is no opcode in java that adds 2 bytes together. It just does not exist.**. It is literally impossible to do this, given that `javac` has no idea what to generate. So, instead:

```
byte b = 5;
byte c = 10;
byte d = b + c;
```

Is actually taken to mean:

```
byte b = 5;
byte c = 10;
byte d = (int) b + (int) c;
```

And, thus, this is a compiler error - the result of `int + int` is `int`, and trying to assign an `int` to a `byte` is not allowed without explicit casting.

You can trivially have a look at any [list of java bytecodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_bytecode_instructions). You'll find FADD, DADD, IADD, and LADD (respectively, 'float add', 'double add', 'int add' and 'long add'). But you won't find byte/short/char variants; there is no BADD, CADD, or SADD.

#### Lesser known java aspect 2: The compound assignment operators auto-cast.

this: `a += b;` is not actually identical to `a = a + b;` at all! I know that's what you were taught, but this is incorrect. It is, in fact, equal to `a = (byte) (a + b);` where that `byte` is the type of `a` itself:

```
double d = 5.5;
int x = 5;
x = x + d; // obviously, compiler error. Explicit cast needed.
```

versus:

```
double d = 5.5;
int x = 5;
x += d;
```

Totally legal. And results in x being 10. The full flow is:

- x is 5. This is converted to `double` because java can only do math between 2 things of the same type.
- `d` is 5.5, already a double, nice.
- `DADD` bytecode is executed; the result of this is 10.5.
- This is cast to `int`, resulting in `10`, which is assigned to `x`.

Run `javap` if you want to see this.

### Combining the two

Thus, let's break down your code:

```
byte b = (byte) -1;
```

This makes the int -1 (32 '1' bits), then casts it to byte, resulting in `b` having the value `1111 1111`. So far, so good, nothing surprising here.

```
b >>>= 1;
```

Hoo boy. This looks simple but is very complicated. It's syntax sugar for:

```
b = (byte) (((int) b) >>> 1);
```

To break *that* down:

- `(int) b` results in 32 1-bits. `b` is -1 in byte, casting that to int produces -1 the int, which is 32 1-bits.
- `>>> 1` then makes that a zero, followed by 31 1 bits.
- this is then cast back to a byte, which.. is -1 - 8 1-bits.

#### So how do I do this?

Don't use `byte`, basically. Don't ever use the inferior primitives except under the following circumstances:

- You use them in signatures (i.e. the return type or param types of methods) as API doc, essentially.
- You make an array. `byte[]` *is* useful and really does only take 1 byte per item.

For all other things (such as single fields, and local vars aimed at math, such as what you are doing), **don't**. They don't act like you think they act, as you have found out here.

Just go with ints. If you want an 'unsigned byte', just make an `int` variable and use that:

```
byte b = (byte) -1;
int x = b & 0xFF; // x is now 0000...0000 1111 1111.
System.out.println(x); // prints 255
x >>= 1;
System.out.println(x); // prints 127
```

`byte` as a single value (not `byte[]` - just `byte`) **is not more efficient in any way** than `int` or likely even `long`, on 64-bit architecture. Java does not assign less memory (because all things have to align on word boundaries), the operation is not faster (CPUs work in 64-bit chunks already).

Comment: Thanks a lot :) The fact that Java will convert byte to int first explains it all.